# Close SP.UI.ModalDialog on form submit

Tags: sharepoint-designer, client-object-model, xslt

I am using the SP.UI.ModalDialog to popup a custom form. The form uses an XSL stylesheet that uses the GenFireServerEvent to commit the data. This works correctly, but I want to close the popup once the data is saved. What do I need to do to modify this form to commit the data and close the dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am adding this so that others who stumble accross it might find it useful. I got this to work by adding a __redirect to the GenFireServerEvent like this: `onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={WhateverPage.aspx?IsDlg=5'})"`

Then on this page add something like this:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("closeme");

function closeme() {
    tp1=window.location.toString();
    if (tp1.indexOf("IsDlg=5") > 0) { window.frameElement.commitPopup(); }
}
```

This is what I needed to make this work!

Comment: above solution not working for me. can you please suggest me other solution